# Not all Client ID's are sent to Google Analytics through 1st Party Cookie in GTM

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, clientid

I want to use the Client ID in other reports. I've made a custom dimension for this and set up everything in Google Tag Manager.
When analyzing the data, I've noticed not all Client ID's from User Explorer are present in the custom dimension.

I'm picking up the ClientID with Google Tag Manager. I've added a "1st Party Cookie" variable with Cookie Name: "_ga".

Then I added the variable to my Google Analytics tag in GTM.
Previewed the change, saw how the variable was sent and published the container.

When I look at User Explorer from and look at the data from 3 days ago, I notice I have 1348 entries. However, when I look at the report with my custom ID, I only have 1210 entries. How can I get 100% of the Client ID's? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/#2-client-id) by Simo Ahava can be an answer and solution to your issue.

> You could get the Client ID from browser cookies, but if it’s a
>   first-time visitor to your site, chances are that the cookie hasn’t
>   been set by the time the Page View Tag fires, and you’ll miss this
>   information.

There are several options available to come around this issue:

- Wait for window loaded event, and send an additional, non-interactive event with the clientId, which should be available at this point.
- Use customTask, as described [here](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/use-customtask-access-tracker-values-google-tag-manager/) in details, which is claimed to be more reliable and less complicated.